# IF AND Function for three conditions

Tags: windows, excel

What is the IF/AND function to get the desired results as set out below?

```
IF  B18 = "Low" And B9="AS4000" Output  "10m-30m"
IF  B18 = "Med" And B9="AS4000" Output  "25m-60m"
IF  B18 = "High"    And B9="AS4000" Output  "50m-100m"
```

Comment: Please be more specific on the actual problem you encounter.

Comment: What is B18 and B9 ?

Comment: What is inside thoose cells? Show start table

Comment: Cheers Guys - got it figured.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the IF and the AND functions together, e.g.

```
=IF(AND(B18="Low",B9="AS4000"),"10m-30m","")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(B9="AS4000";if(B18 = "Low";"10m-30m";if(B18 = "Med";"25m-60m";"50m-100m"));"")
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, an array lookup is clearer than multiple nested `IF`s:

```
=IF(B9="AS4000",INDEX({"10m-30m","25m-60m","50m-100m"},
            MATCH(B18,{"Low",    "Med",    "High"    },0)))
```